# I cant get text from atribute span in bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup

when i try to get text i have a output like:

```py
price = item.find('span').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

code:

```py
#___IMPORTS_____
from datetime import date
import calendar
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#_______________

url= 'https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd'
page = requests.get(url, headers = {'User- 
Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})
#print(f'Status code  is: {page.status_code}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('div', class_='first 
inlineblock')[0]
for item in table:
    price = item.find('span').text
    print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```py
#___IMPORTS_____
from datetime import date
import calendar
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#_______________

url= 'https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd'
page = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})
#print(f'Status code  is: {page.status_code}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('div', class_='first inlineblock')
for item in table:
    price = item.find('span', class_='float_lang_base_2')
    print(price.text)
    
1.1753
1.1752
 - 0.4
```

Or if you require the field:

```py
for item in table:
    field = item.find('span', class_='float_lang_base_1')
    price = item.find('span', class_='float_lang_base_2')
    print(field.text, ':', price.text)

Prev. Close : 1.1753
Open : 1.1752
1-Year Change : - 0.4
```